# Distribution of rmeta and rimage on different size disks

Tags: lvm

Suppose I have the following configuration:

- 2 8GB disks (`sdb` and `sdc`)
- 1 16GB disk (`sdd`)
- each disk mapped completely to lvm pv
- each pv added to single vg ("mygroup")
- create 12GB mirrored lv from "mygroup" ("myvolume")

The end result of the data layout is as follows:

```
sdb
├─mygroup-myvolume_rmeta_1
│ └─mygroup-myvolume
└─mygroup-myvolume_rimage_1
  └─mygroup-myvolume
sdc
└─mygroup-myvolume_rimage_0
  └─mygroup-myvolume
sdd
├─mygroup-myvolume_rmeta_0
│ └─mygroup-myvolume
├─mygroup-myvolume_rimage_0
│ └─mygroup-myvolume
└─mygroup-myvolume_rimage_1
  └─mygroup-myvolume
```

This layout does not make sense to me.

Specifically, it does not seem to achieve the purpose of having a mirrored volume*. For example, suppose I lose `sdd`. In this case, I lose `rimage_1`, because part of it is on `sdd`. In addition, I also lose `rimage_0`, because part of it is also on `sdd`. So I guess my question is, **does this layout actually achieve the purpose of having a mirrored volume**?

* I believe the purpose of having a (single) mirrored volume is the ability to have continued uptime due to loss of any **one** disk. In this case, I am losing everything if I lose `sdd`. Please correct me if I am wrong in this observation.

Here is the layout I expected to have:

- `rimage_1` and `rmeta_1` split between `sdb` and `sdc`
- `rimage_0` and `rmeta_0` completely contained in `sdd`

This way, if I lose any **one** disk, I will still have the data for continued operation.

On another note, is it generally recommended to *not* use different sized disks in this way?

Here are the exact commands used to create the setup:

```
pvcreate /dev/sd[bcd]
vgcreate mygroup /dev/sd[bcd]
lvcreate mygroup --name myvolume \
                 --mirrors 1 \
                 --regionsize 4M \
                 --size 12G
```

EDIT:
I tried this again, but specified the pv's when doing `lvcreate`. It seems if I do `/dev/[dbc]`, then the distribution is the expected/desired result. However, if I do `/dev/[bcd]`, then the distribution is the same as without specifying (i.e. the unexpected/undesired result).

Comment: How was this created? Have you used `--alloc=anywhere` when creating the RAID? Some sites recommend that, and it is usually wrong. If not that would be a bug.

Comment: @Martian I didn't used (nor knew about) `--alloc` (so the allocation policy is probably the default), but that might have made a difference! I've updated the question with the exact commands from beginning to end, and added some observations I made a couple days ago. I will look more into `--alloc` and update the question soon.

Comment: @Martian Ok, it seems `--alloc` didn't make a difference. It might just be that `lvm` doesn't relaly handle the different sized PVs.

Comment: Thank you! You have found a bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1518121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1518121

And to answer the main question: no, the given setup does not protect the volume from the loss of any one disk.

For the sake of not keeping the question open, I am going to mark this as the answer.